# Why does lightning experience use a different url for svg icons?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

It's great that stylesheets are included by default in lightning experiencem but where do we access the icon svg resources. Lightning experience loads the svg in what looks like a different way than we are provided with.

For example a lead icon url looks like this: "https://cs62.salesforce.com/img/icon/t4v35/standard/lead_120.png" how can we get access to the standard svg icons without loading static resources or is it best practice to load them from a static resource?

Comment: I haven't found any documentation otherwise, so I've personally have been using static resources, but it'd be awesome if there were a better way.

Comment: It seems like the lightning:icon component is the only way to get access to the path, it would be nice if they exposed the method they're using to get the path for the component :) it looks like there's some kind of versioning going on

Answer (score 0):

You can call all SLDS icons using this method as defined in the [lightning component developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_icon.htm?search_text=icon). Which means you do not need to call from static resource as long as you are working in lightning.

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:icon iconName="action:approval" size="large" alternativeText="Indicates approval"/>
</aura:component>
```

To see the list of icons and what short code to use, refer to the main [SLDS website](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/). For example, the round icon for lead would be action:lead while the search monochrome icon would be utility:search. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, but that requires using the lightning:icon component. It doesn't help if we need access to the SVG URL without the lightning:icon component. FYI notice my comment above.

Comment: Hi Scott, if you need to access the URL, loading SLDS in Static Resources and calling from there might be the only option.

Comment: Hi @ScottMorrison I'm curious to know why you prefer to call the SVG directly instead of using lightning:icon. Please share if you can.